# Angular JS - Karma test failing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

I am new to Angular and i have started with the basic tutorial that is available on the angularjs.org. While running a karma test, i am facing an issue and below is the error log i see on the command prompt.

```
Chrome 31.0.1650 (Windows 7) myApp.controllers PhoneListCtrl should set the defa
ult value of orderProp model FAILED
        Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'PhoneListCtrl' is not a function, got undefin
ed
        http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/ng/areq?p0=PhoneListCtrl&p1=not%2
0a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
            at C:/Users/sanath.kumar/My Documents/Projects/angular-seed-master/a
pp/lib/angular/angular.js:78:12
            at assertArg (C:/Users/sanath.kumar/My Documents/Projects/angular-se
ed-master/app/lib/angular/angular.js:1246:11)
            at assertArgFn (C:/Users/sanath.kumar/My Documents/Projects/angular-
seed-master/app/lib/angular/angular.js:1256:3)
            at C:/Users/sanath.kumar/My Documents/Projects/angular-seed-master/a
pp/lib/angular/angular.js:5899:9
            at null.<anonymous> (C:/Users/sanath.kumar/My Documents/Projects/ang
ular-seed-master/test/unit/controllersSpec.js:51:14)
            at Object.invoke (C:/Users/sanath.kumar/My Documents/Projects/angula
r-seed-master/app/lib/angular/angular.js:3374:28)
            at workFn (C:/Users/sanath.kumar/My Documents/Projects/angular-seed-
master/test/lib/angular/angular-mocks.js:2082:20)
        Expected undefined to be 'age'.
        Error: Expected undefined to be 'age'.
            at null.<anonymous> (C:/Users/sanath.kumar/My Documents/Projects/ang
ular-seed-master/test/unit/controllersSpec.js:61:27)
Chrome 31.0.1650 (Windows 7): Executed 5 of 5 (2 FAILED) (0.364 secs / 0.047 sec
Chrome 31.0.1650 (Windows 7): Executed 5 of 5 (2 FAILED) (0.364 secs / 0.047 sec
Chrome 31.0.1650 (Windows 7): Executed 5 of 5 (2 FAILED) (0.364 secs / 0.047 sec
Chrome 31.0.1650 (Windows 7): Executed 5 of 5 (2 FAILED) (0.364 secs / 0.047 sec
Chrome 31.0.1650 (Windows 7): Executed 5 of 5 (2 FAILED) (0.364 secs / 0.047 sec
s)
Chrome 31.0.1650 (Windows 7): Executed 5 of 5 (2 FAILED) (0.412 secs / 0.062 sec
s)
TOTAL: 4 FAILED, 6 SUCCESS
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the step we are talking about? (in the tutorial) did you edit anything?

Comment: It looks like your issue is that the test isn't finding your PhoneListCtrl. This could be one of many things (e.g. a typo in the ctrl name, not listing a file in your karma config, etc). If you could upload your code to jsfiddle.net or plnkr.co we could better diagnose the problem.

Comment: @surui - This is happening from the tutorial 5. I haven't changed anything.

Comment: @Matt - Thanks for replying. I think that the test is finding the controller, and the issue is different here. Will update if i find anything.